# agGrid - Tie column movement together

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using agGrid to display some data. I've got two columns that I'd like to "tie" together. If I move one column, I'd like it to move the second column with it.

I know you can do this by grouping the columns together under a single header and then setting the marryChildren flag on the header. However, I don't want a header so this solution doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to group the columns and marry them without creating a header for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little jarring... but here is an option for you:

https://plnkr.co/edit/MQwRLl07xp53dMuEWcGr?p=preview

Relevant code:

```
onColumnMoved(params){
  if (params.column.colId === 'sport' 
      && params.columnApi.getDisplayedColBefore(params.column).colId != 'athlete'){
    params.columnApi.moveColumn('athlete',params.toIndex - 1)
  }
  if (params.column.colId === 'athlete' 
      && params.columnApi.getDisplayedColAfter(params.column).colId != 'sport'){
    params.columnApi.moveColumn('sport',params.toIndex + 1)
  }
}
```